# PHP postgres fetch with table prefix

Tags: php, postgresql

The `pg_*` functions ([`pg_fetch_array()`](https://php.net/pg_fetch_array)) return data from postgres.

Executing a query that uses table prefixes, the prefixes get dropped:

```
pg_query('SELECT a.*, b.* FROM table_a a JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.id');
```

Result are the columns from a and b but without `a.` or `b.` prefixed.

How to enable the prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

First, those aren't prefixes. Those are table aliases.

Second, table aliases don't work that way. (They're not something that can be enabled and disabled in SQL or PHP, although another application language might offer some way to do that.)

The best you can do is to create your own prefixes. Starting with these tables . . .

```
create table table_a (
    id int primary key
  );

create table table_b (
    id int primary key
  );

insert into table_a values (1);
insert into table_b values (1);
```

. . . you can alias each *column* to show which table it came from.

```
select a.id as a_id, b.id as b_id 
from table_a a 
inner join table_b b ON a.id = b.id;

a_id  b_id
--
1     1
```

Comment: *"...although an application language might offer some way to do that."* - That's my question. I want my tables to keep semantic names e.g. `product` not `product_p`. I am coming from a MySQL context where prefixes/aliases are used a lot.

Comment: @DanielW. : Rephrased my answer to actually answer your question. (My original answer sounded better in my head before I wrote it down.)

Comment: I asked my question because I want to avoid changin the table's name.

Comment: So there is no way to auto-alias all columns from a and all columns from b respectively?

Comment: @DanielW.: Someone might have written a PHP function that does that, but it would be a little unusual. You already *know* which table each column comes from; that's in the SELECT clause. Best Practice is not to use anything like `select *...` in production anyway. (So you wouldn't select the "same" column twice, as you're doing by selecting `a.id` and `b.id`.)